# Ping devices on local network via PC on Azure VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, ping, bridge

I'm trying to ping a device on a PC's NIC (Ethernet) with a static IP of say 192.168.1.1 (This IP is fixed, it cannot be configured or changed unfortunately) that is connected to an Azure SSTP VPN.

I want to ping that device, 192.168.1.1 from another PC also connected to the VPN. Please see the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxH2H.jpg

I effectively want to Bridge the VPN connection to the local Ethernet port, but this is not possible using the traditional bridging in windows.

I've also enabled the routing service on both PCs, to no avail.

I've done some research but all I've learned so far is how little I know :0

Comment: Can you create a diagram of all devices and how they are connected?

Comment: Here you go, I'll add this to the post as well.
https://imgur.com/Q1cgVyL

Comment: From your Diagram, it looks like you are using Raspberry Pie on one end. I am not familiar with that device. But one option would be to add another tunnel on the device that is connected to eth0.

Comment: I have ubuntu mate running on the Pi, so anything built for ARM_HF I can use. I'm not exactly sure how I can set up the tunnel, everything the software does is like a black box to me. I understand the general highlevel process but the details elude me. 

I've since tried doing it from PC to PC running windows, same issue, even with LogMeIn (Hamachi) set up as a gateway to the other.

Comment: I meant the device behind Pi, can you terminate the tunnel on that device?

Comment: Unfortunately not, all I have for it is an address, with no way to run a program on it. (It is similar to a PLC)

Comment: OK, then I am not sure how to accomplish what you are trying to do with Hamachi. Proper way would be setup a VPN on the Raspberry Pie using IPSec, that will allow NAT traffic, and then use it as a router to tunnel the traffic. Here is a guide to do it using OpenVPN. https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-vpn-router/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and mark as completed if It works.